# How to combine FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, comma and suffix in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, coalesce, isnull

I am trying to combine FirstName, MiddleName, LastName then a comma and suffix.
An example here describes this:

```
Sno. FirstName  MiddleName  LastName        Suffix    Result
---------------------------------------------------------------
1.   ROBERT     NULL        SMALLWOOD       NULL      ROBERT SMALLWOOD
2.   KIRK       NULL        ROBERTS         MR        KIRK ROBERTS, MR
3.   WILLIAM    DARRELL     WATTENBARGER    Jr.       WILLIAM DARRELL WATTENBARGER, MR
```

If there is no `Suffix`, then comma (`,`) should not be appended also there should be only one space after every column.

So far I tried

```
REPLACE(RTRIM(Coalesce(FirstName + ' ', '') + Coalesce(MiddleName + ' ', '') + Coalesce(LastName + ' ', '') + Coalesce(SuffixId + ' ', '')),'  ',' ')
```

Now how should I add a comma before suffix in case if it only exists without using case.

Thanks

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: `coalesce(',' + suffixid)`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CONCAT`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(FirstName,' ',MiddleName + ' ' ,LastName,', '+NULLIF(Suffix,'')) [Result]
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: comma should only be there in case Suffix is not null.

Comment: @User It will not append comma because he has used `+` at the end. Only problem in this answer is, there will be more than one space if middle name is null

Comment: @User yes, my answer takes that into account, did you try it?

Comment: @Lamak,@Prdp I assume MiddleName is empty apart from being null. It seems a few columns are empty while a few are null. So I assume I am getting comma ?

Comment: @User I updated my answer to take into account that `Suffix` can be an empty string instead of `NULL`

Comment: @Lamak looks good but how to get rid of two commas. I just want a single comma.

Comment: @User if you are getting 2 commas it's because there is a comma in the `suffix` column, so you should take a look at your data

Comment: @Lamak sorry I meant spaces as Prdp noted.

Comment: @User So, `Suffix` can also have just a space?, please clarify your question instead of just keep adding details to it

Answer (score 1):

Use ISNULL:

```
SELECT ISNULL(FirstName + ' ', '') + ISNULL(MiddleName + ' ', '') + ISNULL(LastName + ' ', '') + ISNULL(', ' + SuffixId, '') 
    FROM My_Table_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with, please try and see if that worked for you.

```
create table #FullNameCalculation
(
    Sno int not null,
    FirstName varchar(10),
    MiddleName varchar(10),
    LastName varchar(15),
    Suffix varchar(5)
)

insert into #FullNameCalculation
    (Sno,FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Suffix) 
values
    (1, 'ROBERT', NULL,'SMALLWOOD', NULL),
    (2, 'KIRK', NULL, 'ROBERTS', 'MR'),
    (3,'WILLIAM', 'DARRELL', 'WATTENBARGER', 'JR.'),
    (4,NULL,'BARBER','SINK','MS'),
    (5,NULL,NULL,'SANDERS','MRS.'),
    (6,'SARA',' D','WILLIAMS ',' MS');

SELECT * FROM #FullNameCalculation;

SELECT *, 
    RTRIM(LTRIM(CONCAT(RTRIM(LTRIM(FirstName)),' ',
                       RTRIM(LTRIM(MiddleName)),' ',
                       RTRIM(LTRIM(LastName)),
                       iif(RTRIM(LTRIM(Suffix)) IS NULL OR RTRIM(LTRIM(Suffix))='','',', '+RTRIM(LTRIM(Suffix)))))) AS FullName 
FROM #FullNameCalculation;
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something similar and I used `COALESCE` like OP. Using the suggestion from `Mark Adelsberger` my query looked like this:

```
SELECT 
    RTrim(Coalesce(FirstName + ' ', '')
        + Coalesce(MiddleName + ' ', '')
        + Coalesce(LastName + ' ', '')
        + Coalesce(', ' + Suffix, '')) FullName
FROM dbo.YourTable
```